# How to make all roman capital letters as mathroman inside math environments

Tags: math-mode, roman

I would like that all capital (uppercase) roman letters inside math envirorments become as mathroman. I mean for example to get `$\mathrm{K}$`when writing `$K$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A strange request [[edit: it was late when I wrote that—French maths usage had fallen out of my head; I should have known better]].

Here's a short example demonstrating the idea of how to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`B}
\begin{document}
\[a+b+A+B\]
\end{document}
```

Obviously you'll need to replicate the appropriate lines to cover all the capitals.

A short way for doing all those assignments in one swoop could be

```
\makeatletter
\count@=`A \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum\count@<`Z\do{%
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \begingroup\uccode`a=\count@
  \uppercase{\endgroup\DeclareMathSymbol{a}}{\mathalpha}{operators}{\count@}%
}
\makeatother
```

Full example, with a `\mi` shorthand for `\mathnormal` in case you need the math italic somewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\count@=`A \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum\count@<`Z\do{%
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \begingroup\uccode`a=\count@
  \uppercase{\endgroup\DeclareMathSymbol{a}}{\mathalpha}{operators}{\count@}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mi}[1]{\mathnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

$ABCDEFGHIJKLM$

$NOPQRSTUVWXYZ$

$\mi{A}+A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not so strange: that's traditional French math typesetting – uppercase Latin  letters and all Greek letters are upright.

Comment: @Bernard - That was a very useful clarification. I've updated my answer to mention two methods that implement the so-called French style of typesetting uppercase latin letters using upright rather than italic glyphs.

Comment: @Mico: There are a number of packages that implement this style as an option, most notably, `mathdesign`, `kpfonts`, ` fourier`, `newtx` and `MinionPro`. I wonder why it's not added as an option to `lmodern`.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for this information, I'll add it to the write-up in my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your trick properly handles sub- and superscripts? How about $A_i^n$ for instance?

Comment: @pluton — I don't know of anything that can be done to fix the superscript spacing.

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in the [mathastext](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package. Note, though, that this package will typeset both lowercase and uppercase latin letters using upright rather than italic glyphs.

---

*Addendum*: Thanks for clarifying that you need so-called "french" math style, in which uppercase latin letters -- but *not* lowercase latin letters -- are typeset with upright glyphs. I can think of several ways of achieving this aim:

- With pdfLaTeX, load a font family -- such as `kpfonts` -- that provides the option `frenchstyle`:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}
  \begin{document}
  $A+B+\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}+a+b$
  \end{document}
  ```

  Three further pdfLaTeX-based font packages that provide this typesetting option are

  - `mathdesign`

    ```
    \usepackage[uppercase=upright]{mathdesign}
    ```
  - `fourier`

    ```
    \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
    ```
  - and `newtxmath`

    ```
    \usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
    ```

  (I am indebted to @Bernard for pointing out these three additional  possibilities.)
- If using LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX is an option, simply load the package `unicode-math` with the option `math-style=french`:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
  \begin{document}
  $A+B+\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}+a+b$
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: [mathastext](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) has a `frenchmath` option...